# bitmixer.io usage

Tags: privacy, mixing

I am somewhat confused by the bitmixer.io site. I can enter the Adress, where I want to send bitcoins to, but I have no idea how to go from there. How can I send bitcoins into the service? Can anyone advise me how to use this system?

Comment: Can you clarify what problem you're having? Do you have Bitcoins? Do you understand how to use your client of choice?

Comment: Hi Nick, I do have bitcoins and I use GreenAdress as client. When I go onto bitmixer.io, I have the big "start here" - "Add forward Address" button. In this address, I enter the Bitcoin address, where I want the anonymized bitcoins be sent to - the recieving end of the mixed bitcoins. I don't know what to do next? There should be a step 2 (according to the source code of the page), but I don't know how to get there - therefore I cannot put any bitcoins INTO the mixer - this confuses me. (According to a test, the interface is confusing, and I can absolutely understand this :-) )

Comment: Same problem here. Seems to me that at the moment Bitmixer.io does not support GreenAddress Bitcoin addresses, those are somehow different than others.